# Getting Started with Mobile Value Added Service, MVAS

Tags: java, android, iphone, cordova, sms

I am interested in mobile development and have been self tutoring myself android development.I also plan to learn I-phone development and also cross platform development with phonegap.

But being from Nepal i see that if i would develop an app most of my users would not be smartphone users. I seen another option is SMS based MVAS applications and thus would like to learn how such applications works and how such applications are developed and deployed. I have been searching on Google and have not been able to find any resources that goes into technical details. I have found a lot of materials on what MVAS is and what it can be applied to, but not a single resource on how it works and how to develop MVAS applications.

If someone could provide me with some answers i would be grateful as i am really interested in finding more about how such applications work.

PS: I  really do hope that there is someone who can help me out with this because i see that there does not yet exist a MVAS tag in stackoverflow.

Comment: The abbreviation MVAS is not especially popular, and virtually never refers to anything related to mobile application development. The phrase "Mobile Value-Added Services" appears to refer to services offered by a telecommunications firm, so unless you are planning on starting your own mobile carrier, I suspect that you will find it difficult to get involved in this space.

Comment: By MVAS i was refering to SMS based applications. For example applications where user can request traffic jam updates by sending an SMS to a certain number. Most of the content for such applications are hosted by big telecom companies but here in Nepal we have non telecommunication companies that are also involved in providing such services.
Any other suggestions on how to develop application for non smartphone users?

Answer (score 0):

I have found two ways this can be done. There are Open Source Solutions called front Line SMS and Rapid SMS. These tools can be used for receiving and sending SMS and can be integrated with you server using a GSM phone or GSM modem. After you receive the data how you use and handle it totally depends on you. This solutions can be integrated into your existing systems and you can also write new solutions to serve content and other data.

1. http://www.frontlinesms.com/
2. http://www.rapidsms.org/